# Does Linksys LRT224 have to be with public IP?

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, modem

I've got a Linksys LRT224 router and I am trying to reach it remotely.

I've got a another router that's got the public IP going into it and it is providing DHCP settings, port forwarding etc.

So far, I've setup a OpenVPN on the Linksys router, but it refuses to work on a remote site. So my question is, does the router have to have a public IP from ISP modem? Or should portforwarding suffice? I've forwarded port 1194 (the default that OpenVPN server uses) for both, UDP and TCP protocol.

Or does the LRT224 absolutley have to face ISP modem?

Comment: You are attempting to use your public ip address to connect to your LRT224?  That would be the only you could access it outside of your network.  By forwarding the appropriate port to your LRT224 it will make your other router inaccessible remotely for obvious reasons.

Comment: Its a no biggie, if I wont access the other router remotely. I don't need it when I am not on site. So I suppouse I am on the path that should technically work?

Comment: Okay. I got it working. It was such a silly mistake. I configured LRT224's VLAN to the IP I was forwarding to, not WLAN. I still appreciate your input, because I probably wouldn't had continued without you saying that it is possible.

Edit: Excuse my ignorance, but how can I mark your answer as the solved answer?